# margin collapsed without giving margin bottom

Tags: javascript, css, margin

[image]

as you can see above, if I don't give margin-bottom on 2017/08/17, it won't show its child tag....
I used margin auto but it won't work either.

I deleted margin bottom 150px and result is as below

[image]

```
<div class="chat-box-single-line">
  <abbr class="timestamp" >2017/08/17</abbr>
   <div class="chatMsg">bla</div>
   <div class="chatMsg">bla</div>
</div>
<div class="chat-box-single-line">
 <abbr class="timestamp" >2017/08/18</abbr>
   <div class="chatMsg">bla</div>
   <div class="chatMsg">bla</div>
   <div class="chatMsg">bla</div>
   <div class="chatMsg">bla</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please supply the relevant CSS along with your HTML

Comment: just remove the height: 12px from your css for ".chat-box-single-line".

Comment: thank your maroune Mhiri! it works